# Converting list to tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, typeerror

```
>>> list=['a','b']
>>> tuple=tuple(list)
>>> list.append('a')
>>> print(tuple)
('a', 'b')
>>> another_tuple=tuple(list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Why cannot I convert the list 'list' to a tuple?

Comment: because you've overloaded `tuple` to your tuple variable, when it's a `__builtin__` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do **not** name variables after classes. In your example, you do this both with `list` and `tuple`.

You can rewrite as follows:

```
lst = ['a', 'b']
tup = tuple(lst)
lst.append('a')
another_tuple = tuple(lst)
```

**Explanation by line**

1. Create a list, which is a mutable object, of 2 items.
2. Convert the list to a tuple, which is an immutable object, and assign to a new variable.
3. Take the original list and append an item, so the original list now has 3 items.
4. Create a tuple from your *new* list, returning a tuple of 3 items.

---

The code you posted does not work as you intend because:

- When you call `another_tuple=tuple(list)`, Python attempts to treat your `tuple` created in the second line *as a function*.
- A `tuple` *variable* is not callable.
- Therefore, Python exits with `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.

Comment: Excellent explanation!